# Confuse on whether I will use WordPress admin_post or REST API?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have router that send at fixed interval some data in POST method to my WordPress website... Which is more proper way to handle the data from the router... is it admin_post or rest api?

EDIT: All I have to do with the data pass from router is insert it to database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with admin_post. The question is - do you want allow others to send data or not? If you want to allow only authorized submits, the easiest way would be to implement some fixed api key, and send data only through SSL (encrypted connection).

Personally I don't use REST-API at all, I disable it together with XMLRPC function (except on websites, where these are really needed), since these both are well known security threats (widely exploited by malicious bots)